# Abrir consola de Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Estoy intentando seguir un curso pero no puedo ni siquiera abrir la consola de mongodb.

Recién he instalado el programa y he creado la carpeta:

```
C:\data\db.
```

Luego voy a la carpeta:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin
```

Y tengo los siguientes archivos:

```
InstalLCompas.ps1,
mongod.cfg,
mongod.exe,
mongos.exe,
mongos.pdb,
```

En el curso y los tutoriales dicen que tengo que ejecutar mongod.exe y luego abrir mongos.exe PARA PODER USAR LA CONSOLA, mongod.exe se ejecuta correctamente. (o almenos eso es lo que creo) el punto es que la cmd se llena como si estuviera ejecutandose mongod.exe correctamente.

Pero luego al intentar abrir mongos.exe hay como un parpadeo y no se abre la consola,
se supone que necesito abrir la consola para hacer consultas y crear documentos, también he configurado el path en variables de entorno:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin
```

abro mi cmd y escribo mongo y dice:
"mongo" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

escribo mongos y dice:

```
BadValue: error: no args for --configdb
try 'mongos --help' for more information.
```

Entonces ¿como abro la consola de mongo? lo que quiero es poder gestionar mis bases de datos escribiendo comandos desde la consola.

También me cambiando el fichero:

```
mongod.cfg
```

para que el storage sea:

```
 C:\data\db
```

y el path sea:

```
C:\data\log\mongod.log
```

Comment: Estás usando MongoDB Server 6.0, podrías ver que versión está usando tu curso?

Answer (score 0):

Para nuevas versiones esta descontinuado el comando "mongo", ahora toca instalar la MongoDB Shell para conectarse con MongoDB, consultar datos y configurar ajustes. Te dejo link:
https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell
No olvides anexar en el path en las varibles de entorno del sistema la ruta de la carpeta bin que esta dentro de la carpeta donde se intalo MongoDB.

1. Intalas MongoDB
2. Anexar en el path en las varibles de entorno del sistema la ruta de la carpeta bin que esta dentro de la carpeta donde se intalo MongoDB.
3. Instalas MongoDB Shell, lo instalas de forma global.
4. Anexar en el path en las varibles de entorno del sistema la ruta de la carpeta donde se intalo MongoDB Shell.
5. Abres un nuevo CMD y en vez de ejecutar "mongo" ejecutas mongosh